# How does Tensorflow compute gradients of reduce_min operation?

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

With a non-differentiable operation, such as a minimization, how does **Tensorflow** compute the gradients? Some kind of *soft-minimum approximation*? 
If so, can I retrieve the **analytical computation** for a specific gradient?

Answer (score 3):

A minimum operation *is* differentiable, or at least you can easily express the partial derivatives w.r.t. its inputs:

### $f = min(x_1, x_2, x_3 ... x_n)$

### $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } argmin_i(x_i) = i\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

This does not hold strictly when multiple values share the same minimum value. However, that is not a problem in practice for gradient-based optimisers in TensorFlow, which can simply set all tied indices to have partial derivative of 1 (or a fraction $\frac{1}{n_{min}}$), with little impact to the eventual result, because ties for values will happen rarely. Ties may happen frequently enough in a ReLU-based network that the TensorFlow developers have considered a best response for them - I don't know specifically what TensorFlow does for that situation.

Comment: Is there any reference to this in the Tensorflow documentation?

Comment: Answer is contradictory. Says ~ "min *is* differentiable ... expect when it isn't ...". In a strict mathematical sense min(x,y,z,...) is *not*  differentiable over it's domain.